# What is the difference between Spring's GA, RC and M2 releases?

Tags: spring, release-cycle

Spring's 3.0 version is now **GA** release, before that they have launched 3.0 **RC1**, **RC2** version Also, there was Spring 3.0 **M2** version. What's the difference between GA, RC, M  versions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Answer (score 409, accepted):

GA = General availability (a release); should be very stable and feature complete

RC = Release candidate; probably feature complete and should be pretty stable - problems should be relatively rare and minor, but worth reporting to try to get them fixed for release.

M = Milestone build - probably not feature complete; should be vaguely stable (i.e. it's more than just a nightly snapshot) but may still have problems.

SR = Service Release (subsequent maintenance releases that come after major `-RELEASE`).

Comment: I see SR versions of Spring, are they Stable Releases? (sp. Spring Data Rest)

Comment: @Slomojo: Never heard of that - I'd look through the documentation carefully to try to find out. (Service Release perhaps?)

Comment: It is **Service Release**, found a little while ago.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: As per ocodo - SR is Service Release, as detailed here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/26/spring-cloud-service-release-angel-sr3

Comment: @user1955934: No idea, I'm afraid. (I'd suggest looking in the release history.)

Comment: What's really confusing is when there are 0.8.0.RC2 and 1.0.0.M7 like for r2dbc-postgres and 1.0.0 milestones appear alongside 0.8.0 RCs. How does that work?

Comment: @yuranos87: That sounds like something to ask for the specific project.

Comment: @JonSkeet what is difference between milestone build and alpha/beta built ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: That would probably depend on the project. For Spring itself, I don't know - it's been years since I've used it.

Comment: @JonSkeet thnx for reply. I was asking in general and not tied to spring project. I mean which is recent -  milestone build or alpha ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin: I don't know what you mean by "recent" but again, it would depend on the particular project. There's no general rule for this in my experience. I don't think milestone releases are used as often these days.

Answer (score 131):

Refer to [Software release life cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle) on Wikipedia. The whole life cycle is described in detail.

[image]

Comment: The definitions you gave are **in general**, which means that it may not be the same as Spring's usage.

Comment: It also doesn't explain where the M2 "milestone" fits in.

Answer (score 29):

I think:

- GA - Generally Available, or publicly allowed to brutalized and subjected to intense torture.
- RC- Hmm, these could be a good candidate to release to the public and also see if there are any critical bug remaining.
- M2- Hmm, we have reached the 2nd milestone in our project plan, let's see what the users think and gather some ideas about the bugs that may still persist.

Usually, its Milestone release, then RC releases and then a GA release.

In an Open Source project, you usually would have a *public* plan for releases, which can actually give you good ideas about the project's release plans. Like, what quality criteria determines a RC, GA or a Milestone release.

Comment: race around condition between the answers:
Jon Skeet:   
answered Jan 21 '10 at 7:12 
Amit:
answered Jan 21 '10 at 7:13

Answer (score 0):

**G.A** -> General Availability (Stable, Secure, Compatible for everyone)
**R.C** -> Release Candidate (Stable, Pretty secure, Very low bug, For close developers)
**E.A** -> Early Access (Unstable, Not secure, Buggy, Only for Java SE Engineers)