# Mybatis and Spring Boot 2.5

Tags: mybatis

Will Mybatis support Spring Boot 2.5? Currently Mybatis Framework is shown as an unsupported Dependency on the Spring initializer Site for Spring Boot 2.5.0 M1 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will once it reaches GA.
'M1' means it still is a milestone release.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32370643/1261766) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Even 2.5.0 GA can not choose Mybatis Framework In Initializr,
but I hear it is [preparing now](https://twitter.com/kazuki43zoo/status/1397529563937210368?s=20).

Besides, I can still use it by adding `mybatis-spring-boot-starter` to dependencies.