Maven artifact version convention for non numeric characters
I was looking through artifact version for JAX WS RI Runtime and saw the following two versions:
4.0.0-M1 and 4.0.0  The are additional 4.0.0-M 1through 4.
Does the -M* denote a minor version? I tried searching for documentation and while I found sources the specified what version numbers mean, nothing indicated that alpha characters might denote.

Mn would normally mean a "milestone" -- Apache say: "After some of the planned features are added, a committer may propose a milestone build. Milestone builds are not official releases, each is just a snapshot, so formal vote is not required, only lazy consensus. They may be tagged in Git and are made available via https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/roller. They are meant for testing only and not intended for production use, so there will be no migration scripts to help folks migrate data from milestone M1 to M2, etc." -- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ROLLER/Release+Process

@tgdavies Last question, why did you leave such a well documented and great answer as a comment rather than a answer?

A good answer would research how the jax project, specifically, treats milestones.

This outlines the spring versioning conventions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356053/what-is-a-spring-milestone
