# What does the R means in software versions?

Tags: versioning, release, software-distribution

Many software I have seen in open source projects, have just some versions with a r1 or r2 suffix, but it looks like Google is unable to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how companies name the versions. Usually R could mean Release. Spring follows RC naming which means Release Candidate(RC).

I found this old SO thread - [What is the difference between GA, RC and M2 release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107484/what-is-the-difference-between-ga-rc-and-m2-release)

Comment: Why would someone add an R instead of bumping up the version number?

Comment: If someone wants to differentiate between same release version number but with different builds (public, release ready, milestone, Dev), then these names are useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is also often used as **revision** number.

E.G. **Gentoo** packages use **rX** to indicate a revision applying **Gentoo** specific patches to the package.

The answer @RolsonQuadras provided is nonetheless correct, too.