# What does .RELEASE mean in Spring Framework versions

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml, versioning, semantic-versioning

What does the `.RELEASE` ending to a file mean?

e.g.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: It means that is an official stable Version. Not a developement version

Comment: see this other question for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107484/what-is-the-difference-between-ga-rc-and-m2-release

Comment: Maybe do you know why version worked with e.g. `3.0.0.RELEASE` and not `${org.springframework.social.google-version}` while running maven project

Comment: We assume it's a release by default if there is no suffix. I think this is unnecesarry as few people does it. The author may have certain considerations but it shoud not be a must.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The ".RELEASE" suffix was used in older Spring releases, but [was dropped](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/30/updates-to-spring-versions) in 2020.  It indicates that the version is the release version of the software, rather than a [pre-release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning#Pre-release_versions) version.

### Pre-2020 naming scheme

Per this (now-defunct) [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-build-gradle/wiki/Spring-project-versioning#release-type-semantics), the pre-2020 naming scheme was `{major}.{minor}.{micro}.{release_type}`, where `release_type` was one of the following:

> - **BUILD-SNAPSHOT**: A release currently in development. Such artifacts are typically produced by a nightly CI build, such as SPR-TRUNKSNAPSHOT or INT-NIGHTLY, and deployed to http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot.
> - **M#**: A 'milestone' release. Such artifacts are usually produced manually, following the release process and are deployed to http://maven.springframework.org/milestone.
> - **RC#**: A 'GA release candidate'. Such artifacts are produced with the exact same release process as milestones, and are also deployed to http://maven.springframework.org/milestone.
> - **RELEASE**: A GA (Generally Available) release. Again, produced using the same release process. In this case, deployment happens (a) to http://maven.springframework.org/release and (b) to Maven Central.

### Current naming scheme

The [current naming scheme](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/30/updates-to-spring-versions#project-module-version-changes) used for new Spring releases is `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH[-MODIFIER]`, with no modifier used for release versions.

> - `MODIFIER` is an optional modifier such that `<COUNT>` is an incremented 1-based number:
>
>   - For milestones, we will use `M<COUNT>` .
>   - For release candidates, we will use `RC<COUNT>` .
>   - For snapshots, we will use `-SNAPSHOT`. Note that `.BUILD` that was present in our previous scheme has been removed.
>   - For releases, there will be no modifier.

### Naming scheme comparison

| Release Type | Current | Previous |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Snapshot | 5.2.0-SNAPSHOT | 5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT |
| Milestone | 5.2.0-M1 | 5.2.0.M1 |
| Release Candidate | 5.2.0-RC1 | 5.2.0.RC1 |
| Release | 5.2.0 | 5.2.0.RELEASE |