# What is springboot versioning convention?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Can anybody please explain what is the meaning of `PRE, SNAPSHOTS, GA and Current` for spring-boot versions?

Below is a screenshot of versions shown on spring-boot website.

[image]

Also, latest version contains `M3` appended in end just before **PRE**.

Please help!

Comment: Refer this question on [Spring Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107484/what-is-the-difference-between-springs-ga-rc-and-m2-releases)

Comment: this link is not completely answering my question. In snapshot notice that 1.5.7 is still a SNAPSHOT. Do this mean that it never got released for usage?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**GA**

GA as in `general availability` are versions that have been released to the public. A version that has had this status for once will never change its contents.

**CURRENT**

The most recent **GA** release that should usually be used for all new projects.

**PRE**

`pre release` versions will also not change but are only released to let developers test the features of an upcoming **GA** release. They might contain some bugs that will be fixed in a later pre release of the same version (i.e. bugs in `2.0.0 M1` will probably be fixed in `2.0.0 M2`). `M` is short for milestone.

**SNAPSHOT**

Same as **PRE** but this version is usually built every night to include the most recent changes. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it) question on more about snapshots. Might also contain bugs.

**Version life cycle**

The usual life cycle of a single version would be as follows on the example of version `1.0.0`:

- `1.0.0 SNAPSHOT` those releases are built every day, replacing earlier snapshots of the same version
- `1.0.0 M1` once a development milestone was reached a single build is made that is called `M#`. For the next milestone `#` is increased by one. Milestones are never overwritten. Snapshots are continued to be made every day.
- `1.0.0 GA` once the last milestone was released and the latest snapshot is feature complete and all known bugs are fixed the `general availability` release is made. From there on no other Releases of the same version are made, i.e. no more snapshots or milestones.

If bugs are found in a `GA` release the last version number is increased by one (i.e. `1.0.0` to `1.0.1` and a new release cycle is being started).

Comment: Do this means that springboot version1.5.7 SNAPSHOT is never released?

Comment: To say it clear in this case `1.5.7-SNAPSHOT` means it has not been released yet...I can't answer if Spring will release it ever...

Comment: We will. `1.5.7.RELEASE` is due Sep 12, check [the milestone page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestones)