# What do all this different versions tell me?

Tags: java, spring

I'm still starting with Spring and I'm asking myself what are all this different hashtags before the version

https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas#learn

(GA, Snapshot, PRE..)

Should I always use the current version or how can I understand this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107484/what-is-the-difference-between-springs-ga-rc-and-m2-releases

Comment: You need to read about the software release life cycle. It's not a Spring thing. Please, have a look at wiki's article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the latest `GA` which means general availability. Its the latest stable release

`PRE` is a release candidate. You can look at it as a beta version that is done before a `GA` so its not stable and might contain breaking changes

`SNAPSHOT` is the version under development. Do not use this version because it will not be stable and it will change continuously