# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I got error in encoding my inMemory User password using BCryptPasswordEncoder

here is my springsecurityconfig file

## SpringSecurityConfig class

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

How can i properly encode the password without getting bean creation error

Comment: please enable spring security debug logs and post your full logs here pls

Comment: does the order matter in the HttpSecurity configure chain

Answer (score 0):

You can use a more component-based approach to do that since the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated in `5.7.0-M2`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain appSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        User admin = User.withUsername("admin")
            .password(encoder.encode("password"))
            .roles("USER").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

This way, you have in-memory authentication by providing a `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` as the implementation of `UserDetailsService`, and this bean is dependent on the `PasswordEncoder`.

You can find more detail on the [reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.7.0-M3/servlet/authentication/passwords/in-memory.html).

Comment: he has not stated he is using any form of prerelease

Comment: Where did I recommend they to use the prerelease?

Comment: M = Milestone release, is not a full stable release https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107490/1840146 current stable version at the time of writing is 5.6.4

Comment: Still I don't see my recommendation to use the milestone. I just stated that the class is gonna be deprecated in the future and a more robust solution is available for them

Comment: As of time of writing, the class is not deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate configuration class and move passwordEncoder() method to it.

Example:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class PasswordEncoderConfig {

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

And then modify SpringSecurityConfig as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Autowired
 private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; //new line

 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication) throws Exception {
    authentication.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("admin")
      .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password")) //update line
      .roles("USER");
    }
}
```